# How to edit source codes on Yocto project, and rebuild it?

Tags: build, yocto, bitbake

I'm new at Yocto project.

The problem is rebuilding with source editing.

The flow which I tried is below.

1. Build Yocto Project ( bitbake core-image-weston )
2. After building, I edited weston source code.
   ( build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/weston/1.9.0-r0/git/ivi-shell/hmi-controller.c )
3. Re-Build Yocto Project.
   ( I don't know how can I rebuild it, so I tried many ways. )

   1. bitbake core-image-weston
   2. bitbake weston
   3. bitbake weston -c -f compile
      bitbake weston -c -f deploy
   4. bitbake weston -c -f rebuild
   5. bitbake weston -c -f build
4. I checked output rootfs : core-image-weston-.tar.bz 
   But it doesn't changed.
   (I added a wrong codes which cause build error, but build error is not occured ever! )

So, I hope to know how can I edit source code(weston) and build it correctly.
finally, I hope to get properly built rootfs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After recompiling the the package, you should also rerun the build of the image. Then the changes should be included:

```
bitbake -c compile -f weston
bitbake core-image-weston
```

Comment: Thank you for your command. It works on other Yocto Projects - Yocto v1.6(I tested it). However, I is not work on my Yocto Project - Yocto v2.0. I'm not sure what is different from other Yocto Projects.

Comment: Oh! I found it works well.
Thank you Fl0v0!
The problem is that the test code is not proper.